# Dealing with the ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have a pretty specific problem that I am not sure how to handle. I am still in development of an Android app, and part of that app involves a ViewPager and a set of Fragments that act as sort of a wizard (submittal of a report) where the last report in the ViewPager is as submit button that sends data back to the report. My problem is when the report is submitted, I need to destroy the ViewPager so that when the user attempts to submit the report again, it is completely new. I am looking for a feasible way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the ViewPager in a separated Activity so when you are done with the Wizard just destory the Activity and call the new Activity with the Main Application.
when needed just open the Wizard activity and it will start all over again.